# Geometry - Angle chasing

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, contest-math

An interior point $P$ is chosen in the rectangle ABCD such that $∠AP D + ∠BP C = 180◦$
.

Find
$∠DAP + ∠BCP$

Since also $\angle APB + \angle CPD = 180◦$
and by symmetry (you can swap $B$ and $D$)

it is equivalent to calculating $\angle BAP + \angle DCP$

but then if it is the same, and the $2$ sums add to $180◦$, each sum is $90◦$
therefore, the answer is $90◦$.

I have a feeling that this reasoning is wrong, can someone correct where I am going wrong and supply a rigorous solution.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment on your approach but I can give you a rigorous solution.

Reflecting $P$ about $BC$, we have $P_R$. $P_L$ is similarly obtained. Note that (1) $P_LPP_R$ is a straight line that parallels $AB$ because $P_R$ is the result of successive reflections about two parallel axes of $P_L$; and also (2) $AB = … = 0.5 P_LP_R$.

[image]

By symmetry, the two green-shaded angles are equal. The same is true for the red-shaded angles.
The fact that “$\angle green –shaded + \angle red-shaded = 180^0$” makes $P_L, X, P_R, Y$ con-cyclic; where $X$ is the intersection of $P_RB$ extended and $P_LA$ extended. $Y$ is similarly defined.

Using the results stated in the first paragraph, we can say $XB = BP_R$ [converse of midpoint theorem]. Another consequence is XPY is straight line because $\angle XPP_R = \angle YPP_R = 90^0$.

Then, $\angle 1 = \angle 2 = \angle 3 = \angle 4 = \angle 5 =\angle 6$

$∴ \angle 1 + \angle 7 = \angle 6 + \angle 7 = 90^0$